# Mongoose require model in model

Tags: express, mongoose, static-methods, require

i want to use a static-method from another model in a model. But when i require the other model and call the function:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isCalculated' of undefined
```

so.. is it not possible to require a model in another model? :(

The models are in the same folder, so I call

```
var Confirmation = require("./confirmation").Confirmation;
```

and export in confirmation:

```
module.exports = {
Confirmation: mongoose.model('Confirmation', confirmationSchema)
};
```

Thanks :)

Update: The code:`invoice.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
var Moment = 'Moment';
var moment = require('moment');
var Currency = mongoose.Types.Currency;
var Confirmation = require("./confirmation.js");
autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection);

var invoiceSchema = new Schema({...}); //invoiceSchema

invoiceSchema.statics.insert= function(invoice, cb) {
....
Confirmation.isCalculated(..) //error here
....
}

module.exports = mongoose.model("Invoice", invoiceSchema);
```

And the code of: `confirmation.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Invoice = require("./invoice.js");

var confirmationSchema = new Schema({...});

confirmationSchema.statics.isCalculated = function(pid, aid, cb) {...};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Confirmation', confirmationSchema)
```

Comment: Can you show how/where you declare the `isCalculated` method?

Comment: in the confirmation: `confirmationSchema.statics.isCalculated = function(pid, aid, cb) {..})`

Comment: Can you show the exact code? If, for instance, you add that static method _after_ you created the model, you'd get such an error.

Comment: i've currently seen, that i require Confirmation in Invoice (the other module).. maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Not necessarily, but hard to tell without more code.

Comment: When I require Confirmation in invoiceSchema.statics.insert - function, then it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that because of your circular imports (`confirmation.js` requires `invoice.js` which requires `confirmation.js`...), the `Confirmation` model in your `invoice.js` isn't materialized properly.

I think you should remove the circular imports altogether and dynamically get a reference to "the other" model using `mongoose.model()`, like so:

```
invoiceSchema.statics.insert = function(invoice, cb) {
  ....
  mongoose.model('Confirmation').isCalculated(..)
  ....
}
```

Comment: For mongoose v5.x and v6.x, replace `mongoose.model` with `this.model`. Especially so in v6.x because it will require adding schema as the 2nd argument then only to return `undefined` on query. I believe this is because all declared Mongoose models are already available within the context of `this`

Comment: @Looi `mongoose.model()` can still be used to retrieve a model instance in the current version of Mongoose if you just pass it a single argument?

Comment: Hey @robertklep. Not in my experience. I discovered it was possible in v5.x but not v6.x. Oh, did you mean v7.x?

Comment: @Looi I tested with v6 and v7. It's also [documented for v6](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/6.x/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model).